# Balanced 403 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, balanced-payments

What am I doing wrong here?  Using this gem with Rails: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby

```
gem 'balanced'
```

config/initializers/balanced.rb

```
Balanced.configure("<%= ENV['BALANCED_SECRET_KEY'] %>")
```

Every request I make to a balanced endpoint comes back unauthorized.

```
Balanced::BankAccount.find('/v1/bank_accounts/BA6gbZuQlDs3GsavKj8iiDhu')
```

returns:

> Balanced::Forbidden: Balanced::Forbidden(403)::Forbidden:: GET https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/bank_accounts/BA6gbZuQlDs3GsavKj8iiDhu: not-authorized: Not permitted to perform show on bank_accounts. Your request id is OHM42265044840811e3abd7026ba7c1aba6.

How should I authenticate this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake.  Using erb tags in my initializer for no reason... Too tired for this.  Should be:

```
Balanced.configure(ENV['BALANCED_SECRET_KEY'])
```